# Vuetify Allows duplicated values in a field

Tags: vuetify.js

I've a field where I can enter multiple values.

I use a combobox for this. (see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQqzbL?editors=1011).

```
<v-combobox
  v-model="model"  
  hide-selected
  label="Add some text"
  multiple
  small-chips>
</v-combobox>
```

with

```
data: () => ({model: ['abc','cba']})
```

My problem is that I want to allow duplicated values.
In the example, it's not possible to add a new 'abc' value to model using the combobox.

Is it possible to do that with a combobox?
How can I create a field with multiple values where duplicates are allowed?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will have to use objects for this, each having different `value`, but same `text` or something like that.

Comment: I already tried but it didn't work. I would like to have control on the method used by the combobox to add new items to the model but I don't know how.

Comment: See if you can update to a working codepen which uses objects with unique values but same text. Then I guess it should be relatively easy to allow creating new duplicates, but all depends how you handle values. Perhaps values could be auto-incremental.

Comment: I think it's not possible without creating a new component as in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GwdyVQ?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

In your combobox do as such

```
<v-combobox
  :items="items"
  item-text="name"
  item-value="id"
</v-combobox>
```

and in your script try

```
data: function () {
  return {
    select: null,
    items: [{'name': 'John', 'id': 1},
            {'name': 'Cindy', 'id': 2}
            {'name': 'Cindy', 'id': 3}]
  }
},
```

You need to use a list of objects instead of simply using a list of strings. 
That way you can differentiate between the label and the value of each item and Vue will accept that.